# How can I make a half-duplex UART to TTL converter for communicating to a servo with a HC04 and a HC126?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, uart, gpio, servo, sbc

I have been trying to configure this circuit for some amount of time.

I am using a HC04 chip and a HC126 chip.

The HC04 is an inverter chip. The HC126 is a buffer gate. I found that for the servo connection, I can set up the schematic like so:

[image: from https://community.robotsource.org/t/re-half-duplex-uart-for-ttl-commincation-and-wiring-w-the-hc126-and-hc04/1844/7]

The Linux SBC I am using handles GPIO pins with 3.3V. I have a GPIO pin in use, a UART (TX/RX) connected, and those three pins are tied to a logic level shifter.

I am also using a [Micro AnyVolt.](https://www.dimensionengineering.com/products/anyvolt-micro) This is being used to handle the 12V of the battery supply to the Dynamixel Servo for powering the servo and all while stepping down the voltage to the HC04 and HC126.

I have all my unused pins tied to GND. Direction_Port on this schematic a GPIO Pin on my SBC.

My questions are these:

- How can I make this schematic work or should I take another route for UART communication from my SBC to a Half-Duplex TTL line on my Servo?
- and...
- Is this schematic a good schematic to use to handle these chips for use with a GPIO and UART from a SBC to TTL line on the Servo of choice?

I have a normal servo with three pins: http://www.robotis.us/ax-12a/

One pin is GND, one pin is 5v logic, and the other pin is a Half-Duplex TTL (TX/RX) Data Pin.

So, I am expecting to see the Dynamixel SDK on my Linux SBC (BBB) with 3.3v Logic to send and receive specific communications. The Micro AnyVolt handles the 5v logic to the Dynamixel from the 12v supply. The Micro AnyVolt also handles the powering of the HC04/126.

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK/blob/master/python/tests/protocol1_0/read_write.py

This link provides the Python3 example I am trying to run from the command line.

I was able to compile the source in Python3 and C so far. Anyway, w/ Dynamixel Servos, there are two types of protocols, i.e. 1 and 2. With my AX-12A Servo, I use the protocol 1 structured sections.

...

I have changed the port to "/dev/ttyS2" onboard my BBB.

The logic level shifter handles my 3.3v to 5v conversion. I think this may get closer to what is going on for your ideas to become added here. Also, Direction_Port goes to a GPIO, TX_Data goes to RX, and RX_Data goes to TX on the SBC.

The software states that I successfully change the baudrate and successfully open the port. The issues lie here:

```
[TxRxResult] There is no status packet!
```

This basically means that the Dynamixel is not sending out the required feedback. I think I need a separate program to run the GPIO HIGH/LOW but I am not sure exactly how to perform this action within their SDK.

Anyway...let me try one more thing. The TTL and GND connections to the Dynamixel Servo (AX-12A) might need to be swapped. I have not had any correct info. regarding the connection at the servo and the below schematic. I will test and get back to you.

Here is a simplistic edit:

[image]

Okay...I have to admit something. I should have asked this question in software engineering because of the DynamixelSDK that I came across and now that I know it is mostly software related, and taken back a bit, I should have not posted this effort or concern under my account. I apologize to anyone who read over it and wanted to supply support. Anyway, thank you for your guidance and help.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry. I added the questions instead of leaving the question on the header of the article.

Comment: The schematic looks ok. The problem is likely somewhere you don't mention or describe in detail. What's the specific problem anyway? Can you better the describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I'm not sure, but reading between the lines it seems as though it "isn't working" right now. So far as I can see, you've not provided any details about the servo, itself. My crystal ball is broken, so I'm stuck at this time. Maybe someone else has a working one, though, and they can help out.

Comment: Sure...let me try to better describe the idea and how it is not working on my end.

Comment: _"The logic level shifter handles my 3.3v to 5v conversion."_ - where is the 'logic level shifter' in your circuit?

Comment: At the Direction_Port, TX_Data, and RX_Data. Those three connections then feed into my SBC.

Comment: Watch the bus and direction signal with a scope.  Beware direction shifting with an OS, you may not have waited for the data to clock out before disabling the transmit direction driver.

Comment: Okay. I will go and test w/ a scope.

Comment: I assume you are using a 74HC04 and 74HC126 - it it wise to use the full part numbers of ICs (and other parts) so we know for sure what paarts you are using.

Comment: Mr. Bennet, yes sir. I am using the 74HC04/126 chips for this project.

Comment: Hello...just to say this to make it clear, I have these items I am using to make this schematic work for my needs (actuator usage). https://www.pololu.com/product/2595 is the logic-level shifter, I have a 74HC04/126 in the 14-pin config. (not FK package), and a BeagleBone Black Wireless to drive communications via UART/GPIO to my Dynamixel AX-12A actuator.

Comment: I googled and found tons of user guides and tutorials for Danamixel AX-12A. Here is an example: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus

Comment: tlfong01: I understand that there are many tutorials but that is for ROS and not my own software. I found many also. I think I am going to have to learn more about how to switch on a GPIO to make my UART to TTL converter work. I will keep everyone updated.

Comment: I have just found that the baudrate was set to 1,000,000 bps instead of my source listing overriding of 9600 bps. So, I will test this idea out and return to their installed firmware idea in my source and return service.